# Change in field created by Approval process can`t call process builder

Tags: process-builder, approval-process

My approval action in approval process is changing field value to "approved". But this change can`t call process builder. Why? Is it possible to solve this?

Comment: did you look at http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/94085/2602?

Comment: was that the solution? If so (or whatever the reason is), please post an answer here so the community benefits

Answer (score 2):

as @cropredy mentioned only action necessary to fix this is to check check box in approval action Re-evaluate Workflow Rules after Field Change

[image: This]

Thank you for your help :)